# Why do I get Sys_error("Bad file descriptor") when I call `close_out` on a output channel?

Tags: sockets, ocaml, file-descriptor

Reading [this article on socket programming](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora187.html#subsec-code-serveur) with ocaml, I ran into this example server code:

```
# let establish_server server_fun sockaddr =
   let domain = domain_of sockaddr in
   let sock = Unix.socket domain Unix.SOCK_STREAM 0 
   in Unix.bind sock sockaddr ;
      Unix.listen sock 3;
      while true do
        let (s, caller) = Unix.accept sock 
        in match Unix.fork() with
               0 -> if Unix.fork() <> 0 then exit 0 ; 
                    let inchan = Unix.in_channel_of_descr s 
                    and outchan = Unix.out_channel_of_descr s 
                    in server_fun inchan outchan ;
                       close_in inchan ;
                       close_out outchan ;
                       exit 0
             | id -> Unix.close s; ignore(Unix.waitpid [] id)
      done ;;
val establish_server :
  (in_channel -> out_channel -> 'a) -> Unix.sockaddr -> unit = <fun>
```

Tinkering with the code locally, I was surprised that I received `Fatal error: exception Sys_error("Bad file descriptor")` each time I connected to the socket. Here's my tinkering code:

```
let my_name = Unix.gethostname();;
let my_entry_byname = Unix.gethostbyname my_name ;;
let my_addr = my_entry_byname.h_addr_list.(0);;

let socket_desc = Unix.socket Unix.PF_INET Unix.SOCK_STREAM 0;;

let hello_server sockaddr =
  let domain = Unix.domain_of_sockaddr sockaddr in
  let socket_desc = Unix.socket domain Unix.SOCK_STREAM 0
  in Unix.bind socket_desc sockaddr;
     Unix.listen socket_desc 3;
     let addr_in =
       match Unix.getsockname socket_desc with
         Unix.ADDR_INET (a, _) -> a
       | _ -> failwith "not INET";
     in
     print_string (String.concat "" ["Listening on "; Unix.string_of_inet_addr addr_in]);
     flush stdout;
     while true do
       let (s, _caller) = Unix.accept socket_desc
       in match Unix.fork() with
            0 -> if Unix.fork() <> 0 then exit 0;
                 print_string "Got a connection!";
                 flush stdout;
                 let inchan = Unix.in_channel_of_descr s
                 and outchan = Unix.out_channel_of_descr s
                 in output_string outchan "Hello world!";
                    flush outchan;
                    close_in inchan;
                    close_out outchan;
                    exit 0;
            | id -> Unix.close s; ignore(Unix.waitpid [] id)
     done;;


let start_server () =
  let addr = Unix.ADDR_INET(my_addr, 12345)
  in hello_server addr;;

let () = start_server()
```

It seems the error is probably due to the `close_out outchan` call in the child process. I can't quite figure out *why* I'm getting the error though. What's wrong with calling `close_out` on that channel?

Fwiw, I'm connecting to the channel with `telnet my.local.ip.addr 12345`

Edit: Also: why do we call `Unix.close s` in the parent process and not in the child?

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the socket twice.

```
let (s, _caller) = Unix.accept socket_desc
```

Now you have Unix file descriptor `s` of your socket.

```
let inchan = Unix.in_channel_of_descr s
and outchan = Unix.out_channel_of_descr s
```

Now you have OCaml input and output channels with the socket as their underlying streams.

```
Unix.close s;
```

Now you have closed the read/write endpoints of the Unix socket.

```
close_out outchan;
```

Now you attempt to close the socket a second time. Since the underlying stream is already closed, this is an error.

The way to look at it (IMHO) is that after you do this:

```
let inchan = Unix.in_channel_of_descr s
and outchan = Unix.out_channel_of_descr s
```

You are signing a contract not to use the underlying Unix socket any longer. From this point on you should be dealing only with the OCaml channels.

If you remove `Unix.close s`, things should work (or fail at the next problem :-)

**Update**

I ran your given code from the tutorial and it *also* gets the bad file descriptor exception.

Possibly this is a flawed tutorial.

It appears that both `close_in` and `close_out` are going to close the socket completely (and so not leave it in a so-called half open state). So I would just call `close_out`.

It might be best to do your socket I/O entirely through the Unix interface. It seems a bit fragile to have two OCaml channels sharing the same file descriptor.

**Update 2**

You can use `Unix.dup` to get a second file descriptor to use for one of the two OCaml channels. The resulting code feels much less fragile to me:

```
match Unix.fork() with
| 0 ->
    (* Child process *)
    if Unix.fork() <> 0 then exit 0; (* Daemonize *)
    print_string "Got a connection!";
    flush stdout;
    let s' = Unix.dup s in
    let inchan = Unix.in_channel_of_descr s
    and outchan = Unix.out_channel_of_descr s' in
    output_string outchan "Hello world!";
    flush outchan;
    close_in inchan;
    close_out outchan;
    exit 0
| id ->
    (* Parent process *)
    Unix.close s;
    ignore(Unix.waitpid [] id)
```

I tested this code and it worked with no bad file descriptor exceptions.

Comment: I added that additional `Unix.close s` call in my debugging/throwing-stuff-at-a-wall phase. Replacing it with a `flush outchan` (as in my edited post) gives me the same "Bad file descriptor" error. Do you think the other `Unix.close s` call is interfering with closing the channels?

Comment: (First a comment: don't change your code in response to comments. Now when somebody comes along later to look at this page they'll have no idea what I'm talking about above.)

Comment: Second comment: the other `Unix.close s` is happening in the parent process. Since the parent doesn't establish an OCaml channel for the socket, the same problem can't occur. You *are* closing the socket twice in the child (once on the input side and once on the output side). This might be a problem, I'll try some experiments.

Comment: The tutorial code gets the same exception. (See update.)